# How can I add custom styling?

Tags: blocks, theming

I am using the [Quicktabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module, which has built-in styles for its tabs.

I would like to add my own custom styling. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 of 2 things:

1. Patch the quicktabs module to include a css stylesheet for your custom style.
2. Select an already existing style that matches what you want the closest and then override the styles css.  For example, if you select the arrows style, override the `.quicktabs-style-arrows` class with whatever you need.

The 2nd option would be the quickest and easiest.

Comment: If i rather the first approach how would i go about patching  the quicktabs module to include my css stylesheet?

Comment: Just glancing at the code, you'd just need to add your own `mystyle.css` to `/modules/quicktabs/quicktabs_tabstyles/mystyle/mystyle.css` and flush your caches

Comment: Off the top of my head, copy the arrows folder and paste the copy in the styles folder, where the arrows folder is. Quicktabs will recognize the arrows copy as a new style. Then just edit the css of the arrows copy file.

Comment: After an hour trying to edit the arrow with my custom css is not easy as i thought it would...need help in understanding arrow.css what class does

Comment: .quicktabs_main.quicktabs-style-arrows,                                      ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-arrows.

ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-arrows a,

ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-arrows li.active a,
ul.quicktabs-tabs.quicktabs-style-arrows li a:hover                 sorry for all the edits

Comment: I would strongly advise against placing your custom style inside the module folder, i did it once and an update removed it.